# My Location - Android - Google Maps API v1

Tags: android, maps, location

I know Google Maps API v1 is deprecated for Android. I am working on moving our application over to v2, but in the meantime, my boss wants me to quick add a feature to the old app, running v1. The problem is most of the literature is gone.

How can I enable the "Locate Me" button to the map? I know in v2 its

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

but is there an equivalent in v1?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is still available online: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

You can enable the location with enableMyLocation() from MyLocationOverlay - docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/

I don't really remember if it also shows the button or is a separate call.